# How to ignore double quotes from CSV file?

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I'm importing CSV file in MySQL database with ColdFusion, my code works fine but I have one issue. I want to ignore double quotes around the words. So my csv looks like this: "John","Mark","Peter" . Every time after I insert CSV in database I'm getting double quotes around my words. Is there any command in ColdFusion that I can use to prevent double quotes? I tried to use trim but that did not work. If you know anything that can help please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cfhttp` to read a CSV file into a cfquery object. For example:

my.csv file contents:

```
"forename","surname","id"
"fred","blogs",1000
"jim","smith",2000
```

You can then read it in like so:

```
<cfhttp url="http://scratch.localhost/my.csv" method="get" name="mydata">
<cfdump var="#mydata#">
```

mydata will be a cfquery object so you can then simply loop over it. The double quotes will be removed and it will look like:

```
    FORENAME  ID    SURNAME
1   fred      1000  blogs
2   jim       2000  smith
```

If you do it this way, then you will need to make your CSV available over http. In a local dev environment this is fine, but don't do this in production. So I'd only recommend this for one off imports (in a restricted environment) or if the data is publicly accessible anyway.

Otherwise go with [Adam Cameron's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894061/adam-cameron) answer.

Comment: TBH I'm hesitant about the idea of making an HTTP request just to leverage the CSV-parsing built into `<cfhttp>`. It's a very heavy solution to a simple issue.

Comment: I agree. It's also poorly implemented. You are better off using a sophisticated CSV parser for that matter.

Comment: Personally I'd probably look to import it directly into a temp MySQL table via Sequel Pro or Heidi SQL and go from there. Hopefully I made it clear in my answer that this isn't a solution I'd recommend in production. If, however, you've been given a CSV file that you quickly need to import to a format CF can use then it's a potential quick and dirty option.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the fields and do something along these lines:

```
<cfset field = reReplace(field, '^"', '')>
<cfset field = reReplace(field, '"$', '')>
<cfset field = replace(field, '\"', '"', 'ALL')>
```

This will remove the surrounding quotes and unescape quotes within the field.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can replace the double quotes by using the conveniently-named & imminently guessable [`replace()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Replace) function. However... you might not want to get rid of all of them. Double-quote string delimiters are how CSV deals with data values with embedded commas or new line characters in them (see the [CSV RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)). If you know you won't have any of those, I can see no harm in getting rid.

That said... a better way might be to not put the quotes in there in the first place, rather than having them and needing to get rid of them. This is the approach *I'd* take with this, if poss.

Comment: Would have been quite good to get an explanation for the downvote.